# how can i merge multiple objects in an array (key value pairs)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, ejs

I'm trying to pass a key-value pair from node js to an EJS file.
using Mongoose for data retrieval
It's not working.

```
User.find({}).select('name -_id').select('username').then(
        users =>{
            let JSONobject = {};

            for(var i = 0; i < users.length; i++){
                JSONobject = Object.assign(JSONobject, users[i]);
            }
            console.log(JSON.stringify(JSONobject));
            res.render("ToDo.ejs",{UserLIst: JSONobject.username});
        }
      )
```

above is the code that I used

getting something like this:

[console pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdwsK.png)

I was expecting something like this

```
[
  { username: 'user1@passport.com',
    username: 'user2@passport.com',
    username: 'user3@passport.com' }
]
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: you need different keys.

Comment: can you pls elaborate? kinda new at this

Comment: An object has to have unique property names, not "username" repeated over and over.

Comment: Also, on a side note, there is no such thing a a "JSON object" (except for the global `JSON` of course =). JSON is string data, what you're working with is normal JS. So call the thing after the role it plays, which in this case is `userList` (and remember to follow JS conventions. `UserList` means you expect that to be a class, not a primitive. Also, don't use `var` in modern JS, use `let` or `const` depending on whether you need mutables or immutables)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the issue lies in how you're constructing the JSONobject. You're overwriting the username key in each iteration of the loop, which results in the final object having multiple username keys with different values, and when you pass it to the EJS file, it only takes the last value.

To fix this, you can create an array of usernames and pass it to the EJS file, try this:

```js
User.find({}).select('name username -_id').then(users => {
    const usernames = users.map(user => user.username);
    console.log(usernames); // checking the usernames here

    res.render("ToDo.ejs", { UserList: usernames });
}).catch(err => {
    // Handle error here
    console.error(err);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

The JSON structure you've provided has a syntax issue because it uses the same key multiple times. If you want to represent a list of users with unique usernames, you should use an array of objects.

```js
[
  { "username": "user1@passport.com" },
  { "username": "user2@passport.com" },
  { "username": "user3@passport.com" }
]
```

Here is version with array:

```js
User.find({}).select('name -_id').select('username').then(
    users => {
        let usernames = users.map(element)=> element.username);
        res.render("ToDo.ejs",{UserLIst: usernames});
    }
)
```

Comment: Most of this code results in "having net-sum done nothing": you're creating a new array, then copying over `users` element by element so that `userList` ends up identical to `users`. Why?

Comment: yeah you right, made changes